# Is Address Sanitizer suppose to work with optimizations enabled?

Tags: gcc, optimization, address-sanitizer

I want to use Address Sanitizer to find violations

```
int main()
{
    int v[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int val = v[3];

    printf("exiting main\n");
    return 0;
}
```

g++ -W -Wall -fsanitize=address -o my_bin main.cpp
-> I get a lot of output from the sanitizer

g++ -O2 -W -Wall -fsanitize=address -o my_bin main.cpp
-> just "exiting main"

So, the adding of -O2 flag makes Address Sanitizer not finding violations. Is this right?

I tried in a Ubuntu VM, architecture is x86.

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Probably because it was optimized away (`val` is never actually used).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, the adding of -O2 flag makes Address Sanitizer not finding violations

Not exactly. Adding -O2 flag can make gcc to optimize out unused variable `val` and Address Sanitizer does not see array subscript out of bounds error at runtime. If you do use `val` variable in your code, both optimized and not optimized build will output Address Sanitizer error.

```
int main()
{
    int v[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int val = v[3];

    printf("exiting main\n");
    return val;
}
```

This code will always output stack-buffer-overflow error.

Comment: indeed .. this makes perfect sense now